# Ms Access is showing syntax error while joining a three table together

Tags: asp.net

```
SELECT XPO.ITEM_CODE AS [ITEM CODE], IT.DESCRIPT AS [DESCRIPTION], XPO.STK_ITEM_QTY AS [ORDERED],
       XPO.RECEIVED, IT.TAXABLE, XPO.STK_MEAS AS UM, XPO.COST, XPO.DISCOUNT_V AS [DISCOUNT VALUE],
       XPO.DISC_V_FEX AS [DISCOUNT AMOUNT], XPO.COST_FEX AS [COST AFTER DISCOUNT],
       XPO.TAX_AMOUNT AS [TAX AMOUNT], XPO.TAX_TABLE AS [TAX CODE], XPO.ASSET_ACNT AS [ACCOUNT],
       XPO.DEPT AS [LOC/SUB-LOC], XPO.JOBCODE AS [JOB CODE], XPO.RECOVERABLE_TAX_AMT AS [RECOVERABLE TAX],
       XPO.RECOVER_TAX_AMT_FEX AS [NON- RECOVERABLE TAX], XPO.ORIG_AMOUNT AS [LANDED COST],
       XPO.ORIG_AMOUNT_FEX AS [LANDED EXCLUSIVE TAX], IT.BRAND, IT.CATEGORY,
       IT.MODEL,PO.ESTDATE AS [DELIVERY DATE], PO.RECEIVED_STATUS AS [RECEIVED STATUS],
       PO.INVOICED_STATUS AS [INVOICED STATUS], PO.QUOTE_NO AS [PO #], XPO.CUSTCHAR1, XPO.CUSTCHAR2,
       XPO.CUSTCHAR3, XPO.CUSTCHAR4, XPO.CUSTDATE1, XPO.CUSTDATE2, XPO.CUSTDATE3, XPO.CUSTDATE4,
       XPO.CUSTLOG1, XPO.CUSTLOG2, XPO.CUSTLOG3, XPO.CUSTLOG4, XPO.CUSTMEMO1, XPO.CUSTMEMO2, XPO.CUSTMEMO3,
       XPO.CUSTMEMO4, XPO.AMOUNT
FROM dbo_X_PO XPO
INNER JOIN dbo_ITEMS IT ON (XPO.ITEM_CODE = IT.ITEMNO)
INNER JOIN dbo_PO PO ON (PO.ORDER_NO = XPO.ORDER_NO) WHERE PO.ORDER_NO = '';
```

when am executing this query in sql server it works perfect but when am run this in MS Access its debugging the error I.E., Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression `dbo_X_PO XPO INNER JOIN dbo_ITEMS IT ON (XPO.ITEM_CODE = IT.ITEMNO) INNER JOIN dbo_PO PO ON (PO.ORDER_NO = XPO.ORDER_NO)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT A.COLUMN, B.COLUMN, C.COLUMN FROM ((TABLE1 A INNER JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.CUST_CODE = B.CUST_CODE) INNER JOIN A.ORDER_NO = C.ORDER_NO) WHERE A.ORDER_NO = '';

This is the code i tried to solved my own query. i have joined here three tables with the use of common column in the each table. 
In sql we dont need to provide bracket after from keyword bu in MS Access requires brackets after from keyword.

thanks for ur kind advise. becoz of ur suggestion i solved the issue